# Android Studio Arctic Fox build failed after update and gradlew signingReport has error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-home

i use command `./gradlew signingReport`  and has problem.

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: ~/Library/Android/sdk/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
-----------
Variant: release
Config: none
-----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: ~/Library/Android/sdk/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
```

and when build,There will be problems as follows.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Parent directory of /<USER_PATH>/.gradle/daemon/7.0.2/~/Library/Android/sdk/.android/debug.keystore.lock does not exist
```

I have tried generating the key. but still encountered a problem.

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"`

Comment: Please include the error you have encountered (the image) as text within a codeblock (\`\`\` `code` \`\`\`)

Comment: Sorry, I updated it.